# How to make a redirect to external URLs when visiting URLs in my webapp + Using Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, tailwind-css

I am learning RoR by building a job board. So, I am trying to redirect to an external URL when someone visits the show page of my Rails job. I am trying to do below logic,

```
Click on show page link -> Check if Description available 

  -> Yes (Then go to show page)
  -> No (Then go to show page URL which then 
         automatically redirects to corresponding 
         External URL associated with the post)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your show action, you can use this method

```
redirect_to 'https://stackoverflow.com', allow_other_host: true
```

Read More : https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to